# Overriding java backed webscripts and changing the WebScriptRequest req-param

Tags: spring, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

```
@Override
public void execute(WebScriptRequest req, WebScriptResponse res) throws IOException {
    SiteInfo site = siteService.getSite(req.getParameter(PARAM_SITE));

    //Making sure that the site exists
    if(site!=null){
        //Making sure that the site preset is of type municipality
        String preset = site.getSitePreset();
        if(preset.equals(PARAM_MUNICIPALITY)){
            NodeRef noderef = site.getNodeRef();
            WebScriptRequest req2 = req;
            //dreamscenario req2.setParameter("nodeRef", nodeRef);
            super.serviceRegistry = this.serviceRegistry;
            super.execute(req2, res);

        }else{
            res.getWriter().write("Site preset is not of municipality");            
        }
    }else{
        res.getWriter().write("Site was not found");            
    }
}
```

This is my class that overrides/extends the web script method called execute. I want to change the parameter WebScriptRequest req

```
//dreamscenario req2.setParameter("nodeRef", nodeRef);
```

is basically what I want to achieve. So whenever the super class calls:

```
req.getParameter("nodeRef")
```

it will get whatever parameter I put in my method.

Obviously this approach is not working. I could just override the entire super class that im extending, but that doesn't feel like the correct solution if "all" I want to do is change the parameter.

Comment: Override `execute`, wrap the `WebScriptRequest` object in a proxy that gives a different answer to that method, then call onto the superclass `execute` method?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to achieve..but how?

Comment: Whole bunch of ways. Extend the class and delegate all other methods. Use a mocking framework. Use the spring dynamic proxy stuff. Whatever you prefer!